# Can we say "we will talk about" in a book?

Tags: american-english

I am writing a somewhat technical book about construction, and sometimes I want to say "we will talk about this term soon" etc... Can I say "talk about"? Or I must say discuss etc...? I ask because this is a book, nobody is talking... Everything is written. The more I think about it, the more I am confused. Although at first, I used it without hesitation.

Comment: To me it’s a question of style—especially the extent to which you want to interact with the reader; when you say “we,” do you mean yourself and possible co-authors, or you and the reader?

Comment: just me. i write this alone

Comment: Then you can say I, or the book, will talk about. Or you can use we. But you should be consistent.

Comment: we use we generally in technical texts like that. so that part is ok. my question was if "talk about" is ok or not. seems like it is.

Comment: Talk or discuss aside, why would you mention a term in the first place before you actually use it? And why say that you will talk about it or discuss it ahead of time?

Comment: @JasonBassford It’s certainly legit to tell the reader where you’re going, build a little anticipation and suspense, give an orienting overview.

Comment: @Xanne I can see that in some essays or other types of writing, but I don't think it really applies to a *technical manual*. At least not without something more than just a *Monty Python*-esque "Discussion of XYZ in two pages!" But that's why I asked why. Additional context would be useful.

Comment: There are many terms. I might use that term in the context of what I am explaining, without going into details. Then later I explain it, and this way the reader can also tie the subjects in their minds. Plus, when talking about the first subject, it would be missing info if I didnt mention that ter there, but it is not yet the place to explain it. It happened naturally all the time. It is just not possible to fully explain something you want to explain, if you limit yourself only to the terms you explained before. As long as things remain understandable, it is even better to do it.